# linux bash array contains no data after while block

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop

I have the code that reads partitions and puts elements in array, but after block `while` I have no more elements in. The last `echo length ${#availableb[*]}` returns 0 instead 3 because I have 3 partitions. How can be done that `availableb` will still contain data after `while`?

```
#!/bin/bash

df=`df -PlhB 1G | grep "^/dev" | awk '{print $3}'`

echo length ${#availableb[*]}
echo

availableb=()
countb=0
echo "$df" | while read available ; do
    availableb[$countb]="$available"

    countb=$(expr $countb + 1)
    echo length ${#availableb[*]}
done

echo
echo length ${#availableb[*]}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Note `echo "$df" | while ...` is opening a sub-shell, so the data you store there won't be accessible to the parent shell. Maybe it is best to use `while read ... done <<< "$df"

Comment: FYI -- the referenced duplicate on the top in the list of related questions.

Comment: It is not really a duplicate, because I would like to send a variable to the done like this: `done < <($df)`. But that does not work. On that "duplicate", somebody send a file to the done. That works fine yes.

Comment: It is not really a duplicate, because I would like to send a VARIABLE to the done. On that "duplicate", a FILE is send to the done.  I feel as if I was mistreated on this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
echo length ${#availableb[*]}
echo

availableb=()
countb=0
while read available ; do
    availableb[$countb]="$available"

    countb=$(expr $countb + 1)
    echo length ${#availableb[*]}
done< <(df -PlhB 1G | grep "^/dev" | awk '{print $3}')

echo
echo length ${#availableb[*]}
```

You can handle df var by using eval (NOTE: not tested):

```
echo length ${#availableb[*]}
echo

df="df -PlhB 1G| awk '/^dev/ {print $3}'"

availableb=()
countb=0
while read available ; do
    availableb[$countb]="$available"

    countb=$(expr $countb + 1)
    echo length ${#availableb[*]}
done< <(eval ${df})

echo
echo length ${#availableb[*]}
```

Comment: That works great, thanks! But can I send the variable to the done? Something like : `done < <($df)`.

Comment: thanks klashxx, but I thinks it works like this: `done < <(expr "${df}")`. Do you agree?

Comment: no , you'll need eval

Comment: But eval does not work. Are you sure I need it?